# How to add multiple UIImageViews to paging UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a UIScrollView with paging enabled with multiple subviews on the page: a UIButton, UIwebview and UIImageView. Both the webview and the image change on every page. This works fine. I used Apples [scrolling image paging example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Scrolling/Introduction/Intro.html) to get me started.

But when I add a second UIImageView, the position of image I have in place already gets the new values and the new image doesn't display.

This is the code inside viewdidload for the first image (works fine):

```
// load all the images from our bundle and add them to the scroll view
for (i = 1; i <= kNumImages; i++)
{
    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.jpg", i];
    UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    UIImageView *imageView2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image2];


    // setup each frame to a default height and width, it will be properly placed when we call "updateScrollList"
    CGRect rect = imageView2.frame;
    rect.size.height = imageviewScrollObjHeight;
    rect.size.width = imageviewScrollObjWidth;

    // Get the Layer of any view
    CALayer * imageLayer = [imageView2 layer];
    [imageLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [imageLayer setCornerRadius:7.0];

    // You can even add a border
    [imageLayer setBorderWidth:1.0];
    [imageLayer setBorderColor:[[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor]];

    imageView2.frame = rect;
    imageView2.tag = i; // tag our images for later use when we place them in serial fashion  


    [scrollView1 addSubview:imageView2];

}

[self layoutScrollImages];  // now place the photos in serial layout within the scrollview
```

This is the code to layout the first image on every page, different image per page(outside viewdidload)(works fine):

```
// layout images for imageview1
- (void)layoutScrollImages
{
UIImageView *imageView = nil;
NSArray *subviews = [scrollView1 subviews];

// reposition all image subviews in a horizontal serial fashion
CGFloat curXLoc = 10;
for (imageView in subviews)
{
    if ([imageView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]] && imageView.tag > 0)
    {
        CGRect frame = imageView.frame;
        frame.origin = CGPointMake(curXLoc, 50);
        imageView.frame = frame;

        curXLoc += (kScrollObjWidth);
    }
}

// set the content size so it can be scrollable
[scrollView1 setContentSize:CGSizeMake((kNumImages * kScrollObjWidth), [scrollView1 bounds].size.height)];
}
```

This is the code for the second image (inside viewdidload): (when i remove [self layoutNavScrollImages]; the image loads only on the first page)

```
for (i = 1; i <= kNumImages; i++)
{

    UIImage *navBarImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationbar.png"];
    UIImageView *imageViewNavBar = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:navBarImage];

    // setup each frame to a default height and width, it will be properly placed when we call "updateScrollList"
    CGRect navBarRect = imageViewNavBar.frame;
    navBarRect.size.height = 44;
    navBarRect.size.width = 320;
    navBarRect.origin.x = 0;
    navBarRect.origin.y = 0;

    /* Get the Layer of any view
     CALayer * imageLayer = [imageView3 layer];
     [imageLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
     [imageLayer setCornerRadius:7.0];

     // You can even add a border
     [imageLayer setBorderWidth:1.0];
     [imageLayer setBorderColor:[[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor]];
     */
    imageViewNavBar.frame = navBarRect;
    imageViewNavBar.tag = i;    // tag our images for later use when we place them in serial fashion  

    [scrollView1 addSubview:imageViewNavBar];

}

[self layoutNavScrollImages];
```

And the code outside viewdidload:(this overwrites the position of the first image)

```
- (void)layoutNavScrollImages
{
UIImageView *view = nil;
NSArray *subviews = [scrollView1 subviews];

// reposition all image subviews in a horizontal serial fashion
CGFloat curXLoc = 0;
for (view in subviews)
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]] && view.tag > 0)
    {
        CGRect frame = view.frame;
        frame.origin = CGPointMake(curXLoc, 0);
        view.frame = frame;

        curXLoc += (kScrollObjWidth);
    }
}

// set the content size so it can be scrollable
[scrollView1 setContentSize:CGSizeMake((kNumImages * kScrollObjWidth), [scrollView1 bounds].size.height)];
}
```

Comment: why do you remove [self layoutNavScrollImages];?

Comment: I dont remove it, just saying: when I remove it, the image loads correctly on one page. I need a way to make the image load on every page and still have the page-switch animation.

Comment: Have not yet found a solution, but a workaround that will work for this particular project by adding a label instead of an imageview with the image as background.

myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationbar.png"]];

And then changing UIImageView to UILabel in layoutNavScrollImages:
- (void)layoutNavScrollImages
{
 UILabel *view = nil; 
etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to do this is to make one (big) UIView and add every UIImageView as a subview of that UIView. And then add the UIView as a subview to UIScrollView.

```
[totalView addSubview:imageView1];
[totalView addSubview:imageView2;
[totalView addSubview:buttonView1];
[totalView addSubview:buttonView2];
[totalView addSubview:webView];

[scrollView addSubview:totalView];
```

Be sure to set the right content size or scrollview wont work:

```
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake((320*kNumImages), 411)];
```

Setup views and tag the UIView (inside viewdidload):

```
NSUInteger i;
for (i = 1; i <= kNumImages; i++)
   {
      //... code to setup views
      totalView.tag = i;
   }
[self layoutViews]; // now place the views in serial layout within the scrollview
```

Then to layout the view on every page:

```
- (void)layoutViews
{
UIView *view = nil;
NSArray *subviews = [scrollView subviews];

// reposition all image subviews in a horizontal serial fashion
CGFloat curXLoc = 0;
for (view in subviews)
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIView class]] && view.tag > 0)
    {
        CGRect frame = view.frame;
        frame.origin = CGPointMake(curXLoc, 0);
        view.frame = frame;

        curXLoc += (kScrollObjWidth);
    }
}
}
```

I hope this is as clear as possible. If anyone thinks this is not the right way to do it please comment.