# Add .xib file to a ViewController in storyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am somehow new in iPhone development.

I have a storyboard that includes a ViewController. inside the ViewController, I have a UIScrollView.

I want to add two images and other controls to my scrollView. I read [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773584/how-to-add-multiple-uiimageviews-to-paging-uiscrollview), and decide to implement the idea that described as the answer, but not the way he did programmatically.

I create a new `.xib` file and then add a UIView to it and add my UIImages and Labels in it.

Now, I want to add this UIView to my UIScrollView in the storyboard. This is my code:

```
OfferUIView *newPageView = [[OfferUIView alloc] init];
self.newPageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
newPageView.frame = frame;
[self.scrollView addSubview:newPageView];
[self.pageViews replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:newPageView];
```

It does not work for my UIView which is a .xib file, but simply if I add for instance a UIImageView like:

```
UIImageView *newPageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
self.newPageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
newPageView.frame = frame;
[self.scrollView addSubview:newPageView];
[self.pageViews replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:newPageView];
```

Then it perfectly works. So how can I fix my code to add .xib file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Answer that Carlos gave probably should work with 1 tweak. It sounds to me like your .xib file might contain just an UIView rather than an UIViewController. If that is the case you would need to do something more like:

```
NSArray *views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NameOfXIB" owner:self options:nil];
UIView *view = [views objectAtIndex:0];
```

Either that or you would need to change the .xib file to contain an UIViewController, but it doesn't sound like that is quite what you are after.

Comment: I read somewhere using `[views lastObject]` is safer than objectAtIndex:0. do you know why? in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9648076/how-to-design-separate-uiview-outside-of-any-viewcontroller-in-storyboard

Comment: I'd imagine that views lastObject would just return null if there were no objects where objectAtIndex:0 will crash your program.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
UIViewController *temporaryController = [[UIViewController alloc] 
                                          initWithNibName:@"NameOfXIB" 
                                                   bundle:nil];
```

And then:

```
[self.scrollView addSubview:[temporaryController view]];
```

Comment: does not work. Apps crashed! did you implement something like this or it was just your guess?

Comment: Uhm I've done this with UITableViewCells in that way:    UITableViewCell *cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NameNIBCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];