# xib overlay in storyboard causing uncaught exception

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, interface-builder

My main app is using Storyboard's for laying all my views out.  Next... I've also got a xib file that holds a few buttons that I'd like to apply in a fancy sort of overlay.  This is also working great using a technique I found here: http://www.stackoverflow.com/a/12574190/949538

The Files Owner is hooked up to the main view controller. And from a button on my main view, I can pop open this xib nicely.

The problem comes from trying to attach an IBAction to anything I put on this xib.  All of i have no warnings, no build errors, everything looks fine.  Until I pop open the xib/view, and hit one of my buttons, then I get this:

```
2012-11-19 15:44:48.685 Frolfer[89367:c07] -[UIViewController closeStartPanel:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8352e90
2012-11-19 15:44:48.686 Frolfer[89367:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController closeStartPanel:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8352e90'
```

**MainViewController.m**

```
-(IBAction)closeStartPanel:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"close start panel");
}
```

[image]

It's got to be something just so basic that I'm forgetting / missing.

Any thoughts?

P.S.
There literally is not much code written yet, but if you'd like to see anything more just let me know.  I'm not sure exactly what it is that you'd like to see...

Thanks in advance!!
- drew

Comment: One I thing I did try (that worked the way I wanted it to), was to just add a view on top of everything in the storyboard and mark it as hidden.  Then my button action that I use to call to 'open' it just changes it's visibility.

Of course, the downside is that I have a ton of crap layered on top of each other, and it's sometimes a pain in the butt.  Anyway... I just was looking for a somewhat cleaner solution.

This .xib approach seems to be super clean... if I can get these issues ironed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

Not sure why I didn't try this before, but it works great now.

Usually when I'm in the Storyboard, I'd drag 'Touch Up Inside' handle over on top of my button to see the available IBActions's that I had created in my header.  With the xib file, this wasn't happening at all.  So as noted previously, I changed class of the Files Owner on my xib to my MainViewController.

After that, all my defined IBActions were appearing as I had expected them to when dragging 'Touch Up Inside' over to the button on screen in IB.

[image]

That's where the crashes started happening though.

This morning, I removed all associations to MainViewController on my xib file, and by accident, had drug the 'Touch Up Inside' handle over to First Responder.  I guess I don't play with First Responder much... but to my surprise, all my IBActions were listed in there.  For some reason, I thought I wouldn't see them.

[image]

After a clean and compile... boom, they worked!  I guess the only downside (if you want to call it that), is that in the code view, it doesn't give an indication that your defined IBAction is hooked up to a button in the IB with the filled in gray dot like my other buttons that are directly on the storyboard do.

Oh well, seems to be working the way I had hoped (for now), so I'm going to just roll with it.

:-)
Have a great Thanksgiving weekend.
- Drew

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is there `closeStartPanel:` selector defined for that `UIButton` ? Can you post code for that? the exception clearly states that it is not able to find `closeStartPanel` selector for that `UIButton` in `UIViewController`...

Comment: I have no selector's defined since this is all being built within Interface Builder and I don't need to set them via code.  At least I don't think I do.